# How are webdriver and chromedriver options accessed in Spectron's new Application()?

Tags: electron, e2e-testing, spectron

When I start a new Spectron application (for each test suite) I would like to fix the size of the app (for consistency across all machines and reloads).

Commands like `setBounds` and `maximise` do change dimensions, but they only do so after the app has started (which means that some components have already assumed certain dimensions, which then changes test results).

In the [Spectron docs](https://github.com/electron/spectron#new-applicationoptions) various launch options are available. I've tired to use webdriver and chromedriver options but they don't seem to work. Here is an example:

```
app = new Application({
     path: kElectronPath,
     webdriverOptions: {
        width:1368,
        height:769,
     },
```

I just assumed that the webdriver options came from the [browserwindow class](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow). How are webdriver and chromedriver options accessed in Spectron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
 this.app = new Application({
    path: './ac.exe',
    args: ['app'],
    webdriverOptions: ({deprecationWarnings : false})
});
```

pass the parameters that need to be changed during app launch

and have your new application config in **before hook**

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be caused by a bug. `args` is an optional argument that I was not using. Now that we are using it webdriver options also work.